# Can't Check Children Element's Class Name using If statement In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Want to check child element class exist or not using if statement.

want to check a global variable's children[0] class. if it has the specific one. just want to remove that child.
Here's my code. On the **printCourse** function its showing liParent.children[0] as Undefined;

```
const courseAddBtn = document.getElementById("button-addon1");
        courseAddBtn.addEventListener("click", printCourse);
        const typedInput = document.getElementById("courseText");
        const liParent = document.getElementById("courseList");

        function printCourse (e){
            if(liParent.children[0].className == "emptyMsg"){
              liParent.children[0].remove();
            }
            const courseCurrentBtn = e.currentTarget;
            const courseCurrentInput = courseCurrentBtn.previousElementSibling;
            const newLi = document.createElement("li");
            newLi.innerHTML = ` 
                        <h5 class="courseName flex-grow-1"> ${courseCurrentInput.value} </h5>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning mx-2" onclick="editChapter(this)">Edit</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" onclick="removeChapter(this)">Remove</button>
            `;
            newLi.className = "listName list-group-item d-flex flex-direction-column justify-content-even";
            liParent.appendChild(newLi);
        }

        function editChapter(e){
            const editableInput = e.previousElementSibling;
            typedInput.textContent = editableInput.textContent;
            e.parentElement.remove();
        }

        function removeChapter (e){
            e.parentElement.remove();
            if(liParent.children.length<=0){
                const emptyH5 = document.createElement("h5");
                emptyH5.textContent = "No Input! Please Input Your Data";
                liParent.appendChild(emptyH5);
                emptyH5.className = "emptyMsg text-center";
            }
        }
```

Comment: for sure there are some syntax errors in your code that could be easily solved like don't use `.className` but `.setAttribute('class',value)` or better `.classList.add(value)`; and that condition in your question could be changed as `if (liParent.children[0].classList.contains("emptyMsg"))`. Anyway the whole logic is not going to work for what it seems it's supposed to do (add/edit/remove items of a list). So I wonder: do you actually need a working demo of that thing beyond the issue you addressed in your question?

Comment: @Diego There's absolutely nothing wrong with using the `.className` property of an element, but yes in this case `.classList` is the answer.

Comment: @Pointy you are perfectly right.. I retire the warning on not using `.className`.

Comment: @DiegoD  tried with .classList but it's still showing liParent.children[0] as undefined. although liParent declared as global vaiable. it would be great if I will get a working demo on this.

Comment: then add a condition like `if( liParent.children.length > 0 && ...` because there's the chance that the liParent is empty. But yet it could not exist at all if there's no element with id `courseList`. The reason why there's no answer here it's because you are focusing on a very small detail but the whole game is not going to work as expected (add/remove/edit items on a list)

Comment: @DiegoD definitely id #courseList has one child element. whatever condition I use it's showing that the liParent.children[0] as undefined;

Comment: it's impossible. see the difference yourself: between `<ul id="courseList"><li></li></ul>`  and `<ul id="courseList"></ul>` with this code: `const liParent = document.getElementById('courseList');console.log(liParent.children[0]);console.log(liParent.children.length > 0);`

Comment: @DiegoD you can check it here -- https://bose-it.xyz/javascript/ ; when remove button clicked there will be a message ("Nothing Is here"); with w classname emptyMsg. I am trying to remove that element and add the new input.

Comment: @DiegoD Problem Solved. used liParent.children.length > 0; and it worked. Thank Your very much for your help.